# shortcut to maximize all open excel workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

Is there a shortcut to maximize all open excel workbook at one go?Now i have to double click each workbook one by one to maximize, and I am using Win 7. Knowing that office tab can achieve that, but using tab can not use 'alt+tab' to switch among excel workbooks.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. The window state (maximized/restored) is tied to each Excel window. If you want to maximize all Excel windows, you will need to write and execute a VBA routine.

See this for some ideas: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909200/opening-excel-spreadsheets-maximized